# Different Behavior for Similar forEach vs for Loops

Tags: javascript

I have the following blocks of code that each serve the same purpose. For some reason, the `for` loop produces a different result than that of the `forEach` loop and I'm not entirely sure why.

```
this._domains.forEach(domain => {
    if ((userDomain.name === domain.domainName) || (userDomain.fullyQualifiedDomainName === domain.netBiosName) ||
        (userDomain.name === domain.netBiosName)) { return domain; }
    });
}
return null;
```

---

```
for (let index = 0; index < this._domains.length; index++) {
    if ((userDomain.name === this._domains[index].domainName) ||
        (userDomain.fullyQualifiedDomainName === this._domains[index].netBiosName) ||
        (userDomain.name === this._domains[index].netBiosName)) {
        return this._domains[index];
    }
}
return null;
```

The second `for` loop gives me the expected results whereas the first `forEach` loop seems to fail or go to null every time.

Any ideas or things I'm missing out on here? Even though I'm not looking to create a new array from the iteration, might this still be a good opportunity to use other higher order technique such as `map`, `filter` or `reduce`?

Thanks

Comment: The `return` inside the `.forEach()` callback will have no effect; it just returns from that callback function and not from the outer containing function.

Comment: @Pointy Ah, so if I wanted to achieve something similar, would I save the corresponding match, break from the loop, and then return from the outer function? Or, save to a variable if there is a match, and then just return that variable and do some checking (if variable is null do, else do) from the calling function?

Comment: If you want the first version to work, do `return this._domains.find(domain `... etc. The inner `return domain` works then, but could just be a `return` of the `if` condition itself.

Comment: Reduce could work also, where you push in the an accumulated array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return in your `forEach` callback is for the callback itself, not your outer function.

If you're trying to return a single value, `forEach` is the wrong choice. Use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
function myFunc( userDomain ) {

    return this._domains.find( domain =>
        userDomain.name === domain.domainName ||
        userDomain.fullyQualifiedDomainName === domain.netBiosName ||
        userDomain.name === domain.netBiosName );

}
```

Alternatively, you can use forEach if you instead store the result in a variable declared inside `myFunc`.

Comment: Great answer, and succinct. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The forEach() function will iterate every element and call the callback function given as the parameter. There is no way of stopping it with a break or return.

It don't care if some callback function return a value it will have no effect on the outer function and either no effect for the result of forEach which is undefined in any case.

The forEach should be used if you need to call a function on each item in the list which can invoke side effects.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach